# Django-Matplotlib-SSL: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: python, django, pandas, ssl, matplotlib

I'm building a website with Django to analyse data collected by household devices.

I can create a pandas dataframe from the django queryset (`df.head()` and `for row in df.items()` both look fine), but I'm unable to display the image created by matplotlib.  Firefox tells me:

> The image "https://127.0.0.1:8000/graph/device/" cannot be displayed
>   because it contains errors.

I tried changing the content type of the HttpResponse to `"text/plain"` but nothing is shown.

I simplified my code as much as I could to pinpoint the problem and fixed a few things along the way but now I'm not sure where to look.

From the view:

```
fig = Figure()

for d in devices:
    dev = Device.objects.get(address=d)

    if dev.value_set.values("timestamp", "pcb_temp"):
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(Value.objects.filter(device=dev).values("timestamp", "pcb_temp"))
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
        df.sort_index(inplace=True)

        print(df.head())  # debug

        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        df.plot(ax=ax1)

        break  # debug

fig.autofmt_xdate()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
return response
```

Result of print(df.head()):

```
                           pcb_temp
timestamp                          
2016-12-23 05:05:11+00:00      2168
2016-12-23 05:05:21+00:00      2162
2016-12-23 05:05:31+00:00      2168
2016-12-23 05:05:41+00:00      2162
2016-12-23 05:05:51+00:00      2168
```

Specs: Python 3.5, Django 1.10, Pandas 0.19, Matplotlib 2.0

**EDIT:** I've finally found the issue: I'm using django-extensions' runserver-plus with SSL.  I deactived SSL redirection and now the graph shows.  So: How can I make the graph appear even when SSL is active?  Should I ask a new SO question?

Comment: you're adding a new axes object with each iteration. is that intentional?

Comment: To try to narrow things down can you try to do the plot from the Django interpreter?

Comment: @PaulH Yes it is, there's only a few devices.  Once I get a single iteration to graph ok I'll update `fig.add_subplot` so that each ax is on a different row.

Comment: @bernie I'll look into that, keep you posted.